# Is 笨蛋 a derogatory word?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

I have been frequently told 笨蛋 by my friend when we chat in WeChat. The meaning of 笨蛋 is `stupid` or `idiot`.

However, while we are friends, I wonder whether she uses the term to swear at me or otherwise she is angry with me. Well, sometimes she didn't respond to me after saying the word. It is not to the degree that our relationship gets broken though, as we can continue the conversation in another day.

Is the word 笨蛋 used in such situations or can it be used in more casual situation as well to make fun of the other person? What kind of nuances does it have?

Comment: If your friend called you 笨蛋, It is not sure if that is a swearing, but you know she/he likes you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of the phrase "You fool!" or "you idiot" -  depend on the relationship between the two people, the reason behind saying that, and the tone of the speech, it can be a playful, affectionate flirt,  or a contemptuous comment.

笨蛋 is such a word.

*Of course it is a degrading term. But 笨蛋 is not a word of hate in general. Only best friends would call each other fool or idiot casually.*

Answer (score 3):

我猜你一定是个男人，因为当女人使用笨蛋这个词的时候，可能代表她恋爱了